# Google In-App Billing V3. Check if user has already purchased the Item

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've been following this tutorial:
http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/

I succefully managed to integrate the in-app Billing system into my app. 
The item I would like to add is removing ads. Therefore, When the user first starts the app, I need to check whether he has already purchased the item.

How can I do that?

Comment: did you read the tutorial http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

Comment: @tyczj I understand that I have to call "getPurchases". There's no sample code. How can I call this method, and how do I use it?

Comment: take a look at the sample app that is provided with the API, it shows you

Comment: @idish i want to use inapp purchase in my app. i had read tutorial but i had some doutse so can you help me